# DataTables rows().data() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying to get data from the first column of the selected row, 

but instead I'm annoyingly keep getting "undefined"!
Here's my index page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var mainDataTable = $("#mainDataTable").DataTable({
            "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "jQueryUI" : true,
            "ajax" : "/JsonData",
            "columns" : [
                { "data" : "caller" },
                { "data" : "event" },
                { "data" : "receiver" },
                { "data" : "timestamp" }
            ]
        });

        $("#mainDataTable tbody").on("dblclick", "tr", function () {
            var data = mainDataTable.row().data();
            $("#modalDialogBody").html(
                    '<table class="display jqueryAllCallsDataTable" id="allCalls"><thead><tr>' +
                    '<th>Timestamp</th><th>Talk Duration</th><th>Receiver</th><th>Type</th></tr>' +
                    '</thead><tbody><!-- Data will go here --></tbody></table>');

            $("#modalDialogTitle").text(data[0] + "#: All Calls");

            $("#allCalls").DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "jQueryUI": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/JsonData",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.orderByTimestampDesc = true;
                        d.callerId = data[0];
                    }
                },
                "searching": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "timestamp"},
                    {"data": "talkDuration"},
                    {"data": "receiver"},
                    {"data": "type"}
                ]
            });

            $("#modalDialog").modal();
        });

        $("#mainDataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {
            var data = mainDataTable.row().data();
            $("#modalDialogBody").html(
                    '<table class="display jqueryCallDetailsDataTable" id="callDetails"><thead>' +
                    '<tr><th>Caller</th><th>Event</th><th>Receiver</th><th>Timestamp</th></tr>' +
                    '</thead><tbody><!-- Data will go here --></tbody></table>');

            $("#modalDialogTitle").text(data[0] + "#: Regular/Cancelled call");

            $("#callDetails").DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "jQueryUI": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/JsonData",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        d.callerId = data[0];
                    }
                },
                "searching": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "caller"},
                    {"data": "event"},
                    {"data": "receiver"},
                    {"data": "timestamp"}
                ]
            });

            $("#modalDialog").modal();
        });
    });
```

Can someone review this JavaScript and tell me, what I'm doing incorrectly?
By the way, if you care, modal dialog is done using Twitter Bootstrap.
These are my included scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle and provide  a link

Comment: Unfortunately no, but if you'd like, you can access my GitHub page: https://github.com/arthurmarkus2013/SampleWebsite

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a JSON source `data()` will always return one or more object literals on the form

```
data = {
  "caller": "value",
  "event": "value",
  "receiver": "value",
  "timestamp": "value"
}
```

`table.row().data()` will return 1 such literal (the very first row) thus `data[0]` is undefined - `data.caller` however will contain the `caller` value from the row returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code. It is working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/57nzf2z9/1/).

**HTML Code**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>           
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Js Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You are Double clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
} );
} );
```

Comment: You mean for "double click"? I've tried this, but unfortunately it's not working! Seems, like "click" is triggered way too early, eliminating "double click" from having any chance to be registered!

Comment: Why not you use jQuery double click event here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which row you want by providing [row selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector).

When using inside row click handler you can simply use `this`.

```
var data = mainDataTable.row(this).data();
```

Comment: It doesn't work (I removed "this" keyword this week, for trying out without it)

Comment: Doesn't work how? Be more specific. And why did you remove `this`? What was the problem when using w/ it?

Comment: It keeps being undefined! I even tried hardcoding 0 in there, no effect!